# R: Replacing special characters in a text with gsub()

Tags: regex, r

I would like to replace a series of smilies in a text. I've tried the following:

```
gsub(":)", "xxx", "some text >:) more text :) even more text", fixed = TRUE)
```

- This returns: `some text >xxx more text xxx even more text`

and

```
gsub("\\b:)\\b", "xxx", "some text >:) more text :) even more text")
```

- This returns: `some text >:) more text :) even more text`

That is, I would like to replace `:)` but not `>:)`. Using `\\b` does the trick for text, but not this time fore the spacial characters that constitutes the smiley face.

Yes, I could use `" :) "`, but to me, this doesn't feel like the most elegant solution. What are my options to better control the replacement process?

Comment: You have 2 separate questions here.  It may be best to break them up.

Comment: True, I removed the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
gsub("(^|(?<=\\s)):\\)", "xxx", ":) some text >:) more text :) even more text", perl=TRUE)
## [1] "xxx some text >:) more text xxx even more text"
```